# How do I write generic reusable promise then/catch handlers?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have a number of calls to json endpoints that look something like this.  This is in the context of a Vue component, but really it doesn't matter overmuch.  All these handlers do is display a bootstrap message with a success/error, all the smarts are in the server.

So it's really not all that different than all those `console.log("it worked!")` handlers, except that my handlers need extra arguments.

```
//The Vue component
let myVue = this;

axios.post(this.action_url, qs.stringify(data), config)
.then(function (response) {
      // it's a bit more complicated as it looks at response contents
      // for the actual message
      myVue.$root.$emit(base_messages.EV_USER_MESSAGE, "success");
    });

})
.catch(function (error) {
      myVue.$root.$emit(base_messages.EV_USER_MESSAGE, "failure");
});
```

elsewhere...

```
let myVue = this;

axios.post(another_url, qs.stringify(data2), config2)
.then(function (response) {
      myVue.$root.$emit(base_messages.EV_USER_MESSAGE, "success");
    });
.catch ....

})
```

I'd just like to code the response and error handler once and reuse them.  But, because I need to know something from my execution context, `myVue` in this case, I can't just import a function and pass in the response, or am I missing something?

```
function handleResponse(response){
    //  I need extra contextual variables, not just response
    myVue.$root.$emit(base_messages.EV_USER_MESSAGE, "success");
};
```

which, if it worked, I could use as

```
axios.post(this.action_url, qs.stringify(data), config)
.then(handleResponse(response))
.catch(someErrorhandler(error));
```

rather than repeating a closure with the exact same contents each time.

Coming from Python, I think maybe a [curry](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-currying/) (pre-assigning an argument to a function call, in this case either `myVue` or `{myVue: myVue}`) can do it, but what is the idiomatic JS way to achieve handler reuse, if the handlers are identical?  Anything using built-in es6 is preferred over bringing in an extra dependency like Lodash.

Comment: and how do I pass in `myVue` on componentA?  and another `myVue` on componentB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with currying:

```
function handleResponse(myVue) {
  return function handleResponse(response){

    myVue.$root.$emit(base_messages.EV_USER_MESSAGE, "success");
  };
}
```

to be used as

```
axiosPromise.then(handleResponse(myVue));
```

Comment: so, not currying here, but a closure generator defined in a generic function somewhere that returns a handler that knows contextual parameters?  I like  

Comment: Yes, exactly. Difficult to say wether this is *currying* (definetly not in the mathematical sense, but it is coined differently nowadays IMO)

Comment: that's above my paygrade.  but I believe it to be more idiomatic to someone who looks at it.  novel, yes, but pretty standard JS otherwise.  gonna try it now.